# Jmockit with Custom Class Loader: System class loader does not support adding JAR file to system class path during the live phase

Tags: java, classloader, jmockit

I am using a custom class loader like this:

```
public class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(((URLClassLoader) parent).getURLs(), parent);
    }
}
```

and I'm using jmockit too. for example consider this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new MockUp<Main>(){

        };
    }
```

when I run the app with 
-Djava.system.class.loader=app.MyClassLoader it throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Unable to add JAR file to system class path
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromRunningVM(AgentLoader.java:150)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgent(AgentLoader.java:56)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.verifyInitialization(Startup.java:172)
    at mockit.MockUp.<clinit>(MockUp.java:94)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.attach.AgentLoadException: Unable to add JAR file to system class path
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgent(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:119)
    at mockit.internal.startup.AgentLoader.loadAgentAndDetachFromRunningVM(AgentLoader.java:146)
    ... 4 more
System class loader does not support adding JAR file to system class path during the live phase!
Unable to add C:\Users\hmdha\.m2\repository\org\jmockit\jmockit\1.23\jmockit-1.23.jar to system class path - not supported by system class loader or configuration error!
```

should I add anything to my Class Loader to prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have jmockit on the classpath before your junit / nunit jar? If not, you will usually have problems. Alternatively, you can add this annotation to your test class: `@RunWith(JMockit.class)`

You may also want to look over the [jmockit initialization instruction](http://jmockit.org/gettingStarted.html#fullDistribution) and make sure your setup is consistent with the instructions.